# TypeError: dotenv.load is not a function in angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular

Error:

```js
 /Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/spotify_project/server.js:8
     dotenv.load();
            ^

 TypeError: dotenv.load is not a function
     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nhannguyen/Desktop/spotify_project/server.js:8:12)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  dotenv.load();
}

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
// Setting
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/spotify/dist/spotify"));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: 'user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private',
      redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code || null;

  const authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    form: {
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    },
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(
        process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET
      ).toString('base64'))
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, (error, response, body) => {
    const access_token = body.access_token;
    const uri = process.env.FRONTEND_URI;
    res.redirect(uri + '?access_token=' + access_token);
  });
});

require("./server/config/routes.js")(app);

// Localhost
app.listen(8000);
```

I am trying to get authorization with `Spotify API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dotenv v7.0.0

```
dotenv.load();
```

is removed.

Use

```
dotenv.config()
```

instead.

Reference: [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), [changelog](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#700---2019-03-12)